# Check existing IDs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have several span tags and I need to check for some span tag with concrete id if these exist.

The below example return false though. What could be wrong? [I have an example available at this link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q6FX/).

html:

```
<div id="recipient_list">
    <span id="r1"></span>
    <span id="r4"></span>
    <span id="r5"></span>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    $("#recipient_list > span").each( function () {
        existed_id = $(this).attr("id");

        if (existed_id === "r"+id+"") {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
} 

$(document).on("dblclick", function () {
    alert( check_in_recipient_list(1) );
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you restate your function, like

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    return $("#recipient_list > span#r" + id).length > 0;
}
```

if hierarchy/dependency doesn't matter, and elements with the id `#r*` can only be under `#recipient_list`, you can also go for

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    return $("span#r" + id).length > 0;
}
```

and .. furthermore, if elements with the id `#r*` are only `span`-elements, you can also do

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    return $("#r" + id).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: The second one doesn't "check in recipient list".

Comment: well ... good catch, but we don't know the whole DOM and if it matters if `#r*` is a child of `#recipient_list` - will edit with a note - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your return is exiting from the callback you give to `each`, not from the `check_in_recipient_list` function.

Do this :

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    var found = false;
    $("#recipient_list > span").each( function () {
        var existed_id = this.id; // faster and simpler than using attr, and don't forget var
        if (existed_id === "r"+id+"") {
            found = true;
            return false; // this breaks the iteration
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Note that the whole could be made simpler :

```
function check_in_recipient_list (id) {
    return $("#recipient_list > span#r"+id).length>0
}
```

Comment: you could also use the full predicate in `each` which is `function (index, element)`, but you'd have to do another `$(element)` to get access to the jquery-fct or just go for `element.id` :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#recipient_list > span[id='"+id+"']").lenght>0
```